# SCCM: Deploy software in a deployment collection only during specific hours

Tags: sccm

Ok, new to SCCM, and struggling to find the answer to this one - likely because I don't know what I am looking for.

Any help to set me on the right path would be most appreciated.

**Question**

How do I ensure that a specific deployment collection of machines (devices) only receives the software that forms part of that collection within a specific time window?

**Problem**

I have a site with several hundred computers needing to be updated to the latest major release of Win10 (22H2).

However, I don't want to deploy to all machines at once, and I don't want to deploy them during the workday either.

So we've decided on a 10-day deployment schedule, determined by the last number in the machine name (their asset ID) - 0 for 1st Monday, 1 for 1st Tuesday, and so on.

Each day, usually around 1400 local, I go to the collection group, and add that day's machines to the collection.

Now, my system admin swears blind that they've ensured that the software assigned to the collection group will only be deployed to machines in the collection group after 1900 local.

But that isn't the case - and some machines in that day's addition are having the update pushed out to them within 5min of being added.

And of course this is happening during the workday, which can be highly disruptive.

I've done a little bit of research, and stumbled across [Maintenance Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/clients/manage/collections/use-maintenance-windows). From what I've understood, these are intended to ensure that a collection group only deploys the software between times X and Y on the defined recurrence pattern, doing what we need it to do.

For us, the schedule we're looking at is 1900-0500 AWST next day, recurring daily (with the time set as 1100-2100 UTC for safety, and with the appropriate correct box ticked).

However, even adding this deployment schedule hasn't done the job - and again, software is deploying to some of the newly added target machines within five minutes of being added to the device collection.

Any insights anyone has to get me on the right path with this would be most appreciated.

[image: SCCM Maintenance Window - Schedule Window]

Comment: Maintenance Windows are correct, but they might take longer (60 min or so) for clients to pick up if you're just adding devices to a collection. If the deployment has an "available" period before the deadline, then users may install during Business Hours instead. Multiple maintenance windows will combine together if there's a default one for all day on some overlapping collection for example

Comment: There's a good writeup on these from JasonSandys here: https://home.memftw.com/maintenance-windows-oh-maintenance-windows/